# Yocto project meta-layer for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Is there a meta-layer to beeing able to build an Ubuntu image with the [Yocto project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) (includs OpenEmbedded) for embedded devices (like this [meta-layer for Debian](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-debian/))?

Comment: check this similar question, it might help
[YOCTO how to create a basic ubuntu 16.04 linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725208/yocto-how-to-create-a-basic-ubuntu-16-04-linux)